# How to read from a library standard error?

Tags: c++, qt, logging, stderr

I have a Qt/C++ acpplication which is using a C++ library.

This library has a log mechanism that writes string messages to standard error.

Now, I would like to be able to redirect those messages toward a panel in my Qt tool.
I would like to avoid modifying the library because is adopted by many other clients.
Any idea how to get at runtime these messages?

Having instead the possibility of changing it what could be a good practise for carrying those messages up to the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found a complete implemenation of what i needed...

Thanks everybody for the help! :)

[Will loading a DLL dynamically reconcile its stderr to a main application? If so, then how...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202654/will-loading-a-dll-dynamically-reconcile-its-stderr-to-a-main-application-if-so)

Answer (score 4):

That's very poor library design.  However...

How does it write to standard error.  If it is outputing to `std::cerr`,
then you can change the `streambuf` used by `std::cerr`, something like:

```
std::filebuf logStream;
if ( ~logStream.open( "logfile.txt" ) )
    //  Error handling...
std::streambuf* originalCErrStream = std::cerr.rdbuf();
std::cerr.rdbuf( &logStream );
//  Processing here, with calls to library
std::cerr.rdbuf( originalCErrStream );  //  Using RAII would be better.
```

Just don't forget to restore the original streambuf; leaving `std::cerr`
pointing to a `filebuf` which has been destructed is *not* a good idea.

If they're using `FILE*`, there's an `freopen` function in C (and by
inclusion in C++) that you can use.

If they're using system level output (`write` under Unix, `WriteFile`
under Windows), then you're going to have to use some system level code
to change the output. (`open` on the new file, `close` on fd
`STDERR_FILENO`, and `dup2` to set `STDERR_FILENO` to use the newly
opened file under Unix.  I'm not sure it's possible under
Windows—maybe something with `ReOpenFile` or some combination of
`CloseHandle` followed by `CreateFile`.)

EDIT:

I just noticed that you actually want to output to a Qt window.  This
means that you probably need a string, rather than a file.  If the
library is using `std::cerr`, you can use a `std::stringbuf`, instead of
a `std::filebuf`; you may, in fact, want to create your own streambuf,
to pick up calls to `sync` (which will normally be called after each
`<<` on `std::cerr`).  If the library uses one of the other techniques,
the only thing I can think of is to periodically read the file, to see
if anything has been added.  (I would use `read()` in Unix, `ReadFile()`
in Windows for this, in order to be sure of being able to distinguish a
read of zero bytes, due to nothing having been written since the last
read, and an error condition.  `FILE*` and iostream functions treat a
read of zero bytes as end of file, and will not read further.)

Comment: the library is printing the message as follow:
std::cerr << os.str().c_str() << std::endl;

Comment: i never user a stringbuf... what it's not very clear to me is how my application will know that something has been sent... do i have any event triggered?

Comment: @Stefano If you're outputting to a stringbuf, you'ld have to use some sort of polling.  I usually use custom `streambuf` in such cases.  (`std::cerr` is initialized so that each `<<` results in `sync` being called on the streambuf.)

Answer (score 2):

write to stderr is actually a syscall:

```
write(2, "blahblah ...");
```

you can redirect file descriptor number 2 to anything (file, pipe, socket):

```
close(2);                        // close old stderr
int redirect_target = open(...); // open a file where you want to redirect to
                                 // or use pipe, socket whatever you like
dup2(redirect_target, 2);        // copy the redirect_target fd to fd number 2
close(redirect_target);
```

in your situation, you will need a pipe.

```
close(2);
int pipefd[2];
pipe2(pipefd);
dup2(pipefd[1], 2);
close(pipefd[1]);
```

then, everything write to stderr can be obtained by reading pipe[0]:

```
read(pipe[0], buffer, ...);
```

Comment: Note that it's very easy to get a deadlock when writing to and reading from the same pipe in the same thread.  The `read` must be in a loop in a different thread (or a different process) for this to be reliable.

Comment: And of course, this is pure Unix.  I don't think it can be used under Windows (but maybe... Windows does provide a large part of the Unix interface).

Comment: and probably i should create a thread with a select to wait for messages without locking my application...

Answer (score 1):

If they're using calls to `std::cerr`, you can redirect this to a [`std::ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class cerr_redirector
{
public:
    cerr_redirector(std::ostream& os)
        :backup_(std::cerr.rdbuf())
         ,sbuf_(os.rdbuf())
    {
        std::cerr.rdbuf(sbuf_);
    }

    ~cerr_redirector()
    {
        std::cerr.rdbuf(backup_);
    }

private:
    cerr_redirector();
    cerr_redirector(const cerr_redirector& copy);
    cerr_redirector& operator =(const cerr_redirector& assign);

    std::streambuf* backup_;
    std::streambuf* sbuf_;
};
```

You can capture the output using:

```
std::ostringstream os;
cerr_redirector red(os);
std::cerr << "This is written to the stream" << std::endl;
```

`std::cout` will be unaffected:

```
std::cout << "This is written to stdout" << std::endl;
```

So you can then test your capture is working:

```
std::cout << "and now: " << os.str() << std::endl;
```

Or just add the contents of `os.str()` to your Qt Window.

[Demonstration at ideone](http://ideone.com/9DFJh).

Comment: Very simple solution... my proble is how do I know on the client side that something has been written? should i keep polling or can i have any kind of "trigger"?