# Win32 GUI app: how to get stderr messages into messagebox

Tags: c, winapi

I'm attempting to use procedures from a library written in 
the C language in an Win32 gui application.

The author of this library logs error messages to stderr as below.

```
fprintf(stderr, "Error in %s: %s\n", procname, msg);
```

How can I get the messages printed to stderr into a messagebox?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664/windows-c-how-can-i-redirect-stderr-for-calls-to-fprintf might contain some useful info for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SetStdHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686244%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to select another handle as your process' `stderr`. Create a pipe, have a thread waiting for information on that pipe and set that pipe's write handle as `stderr`. If you define a large enough buffer, you can probably skip the thread and just read the data from the pipe after each call to the library.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code then the easiest way is to just sprintf to a buffer and call MessageBox() - rather than doing some level redirect of stderr.